# convert html table to multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am creating highcharts (stacked column) ref http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked/gray

which requires it data to be display in a format like

```
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
}]
```

But i have same in HTML Table

```
John    Jane    Joe
5          2    3
3          2    4
4          3    4
7          2    2
2          1    5
```

By using c# code behind i am able to convert HTML Table to string

```
string sHTMLTable = "John,5,3,4,7,2|Jane,2,2,3,2,1|Joe,3,4,4,2,5";
```

How can i convert same string in HighCharts required Array format ?

Comment: split the string into arrays, and then sub-arrays, and use the values.

Comment: Could you provide your HTML of the table.

Comment: sir, can u please post some example links ?

Comment: Are you suing ASP.NET MVC or Webforms?

Comment: Example links of how to split a string? If you do a search, you'll find lots of information. I assume you know how to create an Array as well as objects.

Comment: We really need the HTML ***markup***, not whatever that is ?

Comment: @adeneo: OP wants to go from the string at the bottom to the array of objects at the top. The HTML shouldn't matter. ...unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Yes u r right

Comment: You can generate the JSON using C# itself. Why you need to do extra effort on conversion ? Always try to introduce List<Objects> , which is very easy to maintain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the string on the `|` character, then use `.map()` on the resulting Array to iterate the sub-strings.

Inside the `.map()` callback, split the sub-string on the `,` character, and return an object with the first item as the `name` property, and the remainder as the `data` property.

```
var res = sHTMLTable.split("|").map(function(s) {
    var arr = s.split(",");
    return {name:arr.shift(), data:arr.map(Number)};
});
```

---

Notice that I used `.map()` again when setting the `data`. This was to convert the numeric strings to actual numbers.

Comment: 1. why should he needs to write bother about creating a json string. It can be done using C# rite ? 2. What is the `Number` here ?

Comment: @VeeKayBee: If you mean he should change the serialization done on the server, then you may be right. I don't know why OP is creating the string this way. The `Number` is the native `Number` constructor function. It takes its first argument, converts it *ToNumber*, and returns the result. Because it'll be invoked without using `new`, it'll return a primitive. Therefore, an array like `["1","2","3","4","5"]` will be mapped to a new array `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: I was suggesting to perform serialization at server side and since it is a JSON, we can easily achieve multiple device support like desktop pc, mobile, tablets etc

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can get your `sHTMLTable` variable from C# to the javascript of the rendered page (either via a hidden field or response.writing it inside a `<script>` tag) this should work:

```
var sHTMLTable = "John,5,3,4,7,2|Jane,2,2,3,2,1|Joe,3,4,4,2,5";
var aPersonData = sHTMLTable.split('|');
var series = [];

for (var i = 0; i < aPersonData.length; i++) {
    var data = aPersonData[i].split(',');
    var obj = {
        name: data.shift(),
        data: data
    };
    series.push(obj);
};
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4BvM/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Sagar,

Please specify which language you are using.

Assuming that you are using C#

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<String> Data {get;set} 
}

Adding some instances of them to a List:

List<String> abc=new List<String>()
abc.Add("1");
abc.Add("2");
abc.Add("3");

Employee oEmployee1 = 
       new Employee{Name="Joe",data=abc};

Employee oEmployee2 = 
      new Employee { Name = "Jane",data=abc};
Employee oEmployee3 = 
        new Employee { Name = "Joe", data=abc};

List<Employee> oList = new List<Employee>() 
{ oEmployee1, oEmployee2, oEmployee3 };


System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
         new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(oList);
```

This will generates the data in JSON format and you don't want to write any code to convert data to JSON.